# Create a class for a HTML object

Tags: html, class, object, asp.net-mvc-5, html-input

I am coding an MVC 5 internet application and would like to create a `class` for a `HTML` object. By that, I mean I would like to do the same as the following, where I create the object called `"form-control"`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

I have the object all created, with nested classes, but am not sure how to combine these into a class that I can use in a HTML page.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/inputSpinner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text" />
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Bootstrap 3 input-spinner</h1></div>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/inputSpinner.js"></script>
}
```

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Basically, I am wanting to know if I can simplify all the `div class` and `input type` lines of code into one class.

Comment: I really got confused with this actually, you are talking about class, objects, etc. But as far as I know class in HTML tags refers to the css class. What exactly that you are trying here?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Comment: Are you trying to _output_ `HTML` markup from the server-side using `Classes`, `Objects`, etc? If so you're throwing away the whole `MVC` concept of keeping concerns separated.

Comment: Are you talking about creating custom controls/user controls? (asp.net) With these you override the render method to display what you need. (either render() or beforeRender(), not done asp.net for a while)

Comment: I think you are confused about what a class is in html versus what it is in c#.